# How to check the value of a custom resource file?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Hi please help to assist me on this.

So I created a res xml file under folder res/values (fm_login.xml) and the content as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="fm_screen_name"></string>
    <string name="fm_email_address"></string>
</resources>
```

The main purpose is to check this file and make it as a setting page for the app. So later my code is looks like this for main activity

```
    // Welcome message
    String fm_email_address = getResources().getString(R.string.fm_email_address);

    if (fm_email_address == "") {
        strEmail_Exist = false;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please sign up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // View SignUp Button

    } else {
        strEmail_Exist = true;
        String strScreen_Name = getResources().getString(R.string.fm_screen_name);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome, " + strScreen_Name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // View Menu Button
    }
```

Question, when I emptied the value why I can't check if it's empty?
Or should I use null to compare. Because for the first time user I need to make use their name/email is not registered yet in the app/mobile.

Appreciate for the assistance, since it's been pending for a while.

Comment: Why you are checking it with xml string value? You can do it by getting edit text values na?

Comment: TextUtils.isEmpty(fm_email_address ) = true means fm_email_address  is null or ""

Comment: `if (fm_email_address.equals(""))`

Comment: Thanks both. I'm totally newbie on this. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get your `String` `Resource` value in A `String` variable than use **`TextUtils.isEmpty`** to check it is empty or not

```
String fm_email_address = getResources().getString(R.string.fm_email_address);
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fm_email_address)) {
        //do something Your String is empty
}else{
        //do something Your String is not empty
}
```